# Shared MySQL database for ASP.NET and Java

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, mysql, networking

I recently developed a **Java Application** for a client with **MySQL database**. Now he wants to have **ASP.NET website connected** with the Java Application.

I'm thinking of **placing the database on a local server** which would **support both the desktop application and the website**.

What i want to know is, is it the good way to handle these kind of scenario or is there any standard method?

I also want to know what are the steps to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about having both the desktop application and the web site accessing the database, you shouldn't worry as databases are designed to have many different programs accessing them at once.

If you're worried about keeping your data in a consistent state, you should look at using a transactional MySQL database engine such as InnoDB for a start. Also, in both your application and your website you are going to have to make sure that you validate any data going in/out of the database. i.e. if someone enters garbage data from the website, make sure that this will not be saved to the database and will not crash the desktop application.